# Tests for updating avatar in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I want to test this `update` action:

```
  def update
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
    begin
      @player.update_attributes(player_params_avatar)
      flash[:success] = "Avatar updated"
      redirect_to player_path(@player)
    rescue ActionController::ParameterMissing => e
      flash[:danger] = "First choose avatar file"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

def player_params_avatar
  params.require(:player).permit(:avatar)
end
```

I'm thinking about something like:

```
  describe "PUT #update" do
    let!(:player1) { FactoryGirl.create :player }
    context "when data is valid" do
      it "update avatar" do
        avatar = File.new(Rails.root + 'spec/factories/images/1.png') 
        put :update, player: { id: player1.id, avatar: avatar }
        expect(flash[:success]).to be_present
      end
    end
```

But in RSpec console I get the error:

> ```
>  Failure/Error: put :update, player: { id: player1.id, avatar: avatar }
>  ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>    No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"players", :player=>{:id=>"1", :avatar=>"#<File:0xaed5b84>"}}
> ```

Why this code rises this error? There is specific player `id` so should be also correct url eg.

> http://localhost:3000/players/1/edit

EDIT: I'm using paperclip gem for avatars.

My `routes` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/about'
  get 'matches/new'

  root 'pages#home'

  resources :players
  resources :matches

  get '*path' => redirect('/')
end
```

Comment: routes are properly setup?

Comment: Yes, in browser I can update avatar and everything is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem myself.

The tricky line was:

```
put :update, player: { id: player1.id, avatar: avatar }
```

I changed it to:

```
put :update, id: player1.id, player: { avatar: file }
```

And test passes.